# c++ Remove the duplicates in sorted array - print the new array

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am testing out this piece of code in c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int removeDuplicates(int A[], int n) {
    if(n == 0) return 0;

    int index = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(A[index] == A[i])
        {

            continue;
        }
        index++;
        A[index] = A[i];
    }
    cout<<"New array is "<<A[index]<<endl;
    return index+1;
}


int main(){

    int x[10] = {1,1,6};
    int n = 3;
    int z = removeDuplicates(x, n);
    cout<<"Length is "<<z;
}
```

The result of length is right.
However, when cout the new array. The result is only 6.
1 is missing.

Where should I put `cout<<"New array is "<<A[index]<<endl;`

To give me the result as `New array is 16`

More code I need to add? Please help, anyone?

Comment: `cout<<"New array is "<<A[index]<<endl;` outputs the element at position `index` of `A`.

Comment: Use a for loop to print contents of array. You can't directly print a whole array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    if(A[index] == A[i])
    {

        continue;
    }
    index++;
    A[index] = A[i];
}
```

Let's go trace:
A = {1,1,6}; n = 3;

1º i = 0; index = 0  -> a[0] == a[0]? -> Continue

2º i = 1; index = 0  -> a[0] == a[1]? -> Continue

3º i = 2; index = 0  -> a[0] == a[2]? -> Nope, so index++ -> a[1] = a[2];

The new array is: {1,6,6}. index has the value of = 1, so you print:

cout<<"New array is "< 6

You return index = 2 and A = {1,6,6}. This is a correct result, your algorithm works, but the print doesn't have sense. You should print with for in the return:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int removeDuplicates(int A[], int n)
{
    if(n == 0) return 0;

    int index = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(A[index] == A[i])
        {

            continue;
        }
        index++;
        A[index] = A[i];
    }
    return index+1;
}


int main()
{

    int x[10] = {1,1,6};
    int n = 3;
    int size = removeDuplicates(x, n);
    cout<<"Length is "<<size<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cout<<x[i]<<' ';
    }
}
```

This works great :). But, you have one function of standar library for this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int x[10] = {1,1,6};
    int n = 3;
    int* end = unique(x,x+n); // returns reference to the end

    for (int i = 0;(x+i) != end; i++)
    {
        cout<<x[i]<<' ';
    }
}
```

You can check reference of unique here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/

Comment: Now I understand it. Thank you for your help, amchacon!

Answer (score 4):

`std::unique` and `std::erase` are your friends.

`std::vector` is also a good friend.

By the way, your program does remove duplicates correctly; it's just the output statement that doesn't show more of the array than the single value 6.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `std::unique` and `std::erase`, do it in one line using `std::unique_copy` and `std::ostream_iterator<>`. Let me do that:

```
unique_copy(begin(ar),end(ar),ostream_iterator<T>(cout,"\n"));
```

where `ar` is any STL sequence container, and `T` is its `value_type`